# Integrating Helia with a Pinning Service: Helia-Remote-Pinning Error

Tags: ipfs, infura

I am trying to integrate the Helia library with a pinning service, specifically using @helia/remote-pinning, as ipfs-http-client has been deprecated. However, I am encountering an issue with the pinning service integration.

when I am trying to install @helia/remote-pinning I am getting a version conflict between the dependencies

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @helia/remote-pinning@1.1.1
npm ERR! Found: helia@2.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/helia
npm ERR!   helia@"^2.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer helia@"^1.3.11" from @helia/remote-pinning@1.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@helia/remote-pinning
npm ERR!   @helia/remote-pinning@"^1.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: helia@1.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/helia
npm ERR!   peer helia@"^1.3.11" from @helia/remote-pinning@1.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@helia/remote-pinning
npm ERR!     @helia/remote-pinning@"^1.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-06T07_22_09_241Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-06T07_22_09_241Z-debug-0.log
```

**setup**

1. Node.js environment
2. Helia (v2.0.3) [helia github repository](https://github.com/ipfs/helia)
3. @helia/remote-pinning [helia remote-pinning repository](https://github.com/ipfs/helia-remote-pinning/tree/main)
4. Pinning service: Infura

Is there any other way to use a pinning service with helia?

I tried to install @helia/remote-pinning so as to use infura ipfs pinning service along with helia.

```
npm i @helia/remote-pinning
```